# Filter images with Color picker

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, desktop-application

I have a problem to select a image. I select a Folder, folder has hundred of images. there is also a color picker control and I want to select those image which mostly color match with color picker.

let suppose I select color from color picker like GREEN. The Images folder I select to get all those images which has mostly color GREEN like Tree, Grass, Grace etc.

Please give me some suggestion. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this post? It's his first post, and moreover, I find no problem with this question.

Comment: I am still waiting.. please help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, after choosing the path from `FolderBrowserDialog`, you can use [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get all image files in the directory.

After getting the file list, iterate through the list, for each file, open it as `Bitmap`, (Disclaimer: I am not expert in graphical processing, so I don't know if there is better way), count number of pixel that match the color using `getPixel()` (however, getPixel is very slow, I recommend using [Lockbits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead), and compare with the size of the Bitmap, the ratio is up to you to decide.

Comment: Thanks DatVM... I will try then I will inform